# "Notice: Undefined variable: content" is showing

Tags: php, errors, debug

I am using this code if for showing related content form custom taxonomy. But it is showing "Notice: Undefined variable: content"

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Related Post

*/



function pippin_related_posts($taxonomy = '') {

    global $post;

    if($taxonomy == '') { $taxonomy = 'post_tag'; }

    $tags = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy);

    if ($tags) {
        $first_tag  = $tags[0]->term_id;
        $second_tag = $tags[1]->term_id;
        $third_tag  = $tags[2]->term_id;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => get_post_type($post->ID),
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'terms' => $second_tag,
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'terms' => $first_tag,
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'terms' => $third_tag,
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                )
            )
        );
        $related = get_posts($args);
        $i = 0;
        if( $related ) {
            global $post;
            $temp_post = $post;
                foreach($related as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
                    $content .= '<ul class="related-posts-box">';
                        $content .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
                    $content .= '</ul>';

                endforeach;
            $post = $temp_post;
        }
    }

    return $content;
}        


add_action('the_content', 'do_jt_related_posts');
function do_jt_related_posts() {


    if( is_singular('post') ) :
        echo get_the_content();
        echo pippin_related_posts();        
    else : 
        echo get_the_content();
    endif;
}
```

When I turn off wordpress debug, it is ok, but when turn on debug on, then it is showing this error. Any idea why this is showing? I got this code form [here](https://pippinsplugins.com/related-posts-by-taxonomy-plugin/).

Comment: Just a few kind notes here, please add all code directly to your question, do not use third party serves. Also, debugging help is off topic here. Debug errors is quite explicit and tell you what the problem is. *"Notice: Undefined variable:* tells you that you are using a variable that is not defined. You have to simply define the variable before using it :-)

Comment: I was added codes here but codes are not displaying properly. Thanks for editing my post.

Comment: No propbelm, just a tip, when you add code in the editor, highlight it all, and look above the editor, there is a `{}` sign, click that. This will indent each line of code with 4 spaces, this will display your code in a code block as you can see from my edit :-)

Comment: You are appending a string to a string with the `$content` variable, which wasn't set previously. Pretty much what the error message explains you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the actual question is off topic, I would make a few alterations to the code to make it more reliable and a bit faster and less resource intensive:

- Add `$content = '';` right at the top of the function, this will take care off the *Notice: Undefined variable* notice
- Only get the term id's from `wp_get_post_terms()`. This will make this function faster and you will not retrieve info that you are not going to use. Just add `array('fields' => 'ids' )` as the third parameter
- Instead of using the `$post` global which is not very reliable, use `get_queried_object()` to get the current post info
- Removed the counter, I don't see any need for that
- `WP_Query` is just a personal preference as you don't need to setup postdata and use the `$post` global

Here is the function rewritten

```
function pippin_related_posts($taxonomy = '') {

    $current_post = get_queried_object();
    $content = '';

    if($taxonomy == '') { $taxonomy = 'post_tag'; }

    $tags = wp_get_post_terms($current_post->ID, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'ids' ));

    if ($tags) {
        $first_tag  = $tags[0];
        $second_tag = $tags[1];
        $third_tag  = $tags[2];
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => $current_post->post_type,
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'terms' => $second_tag,
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'terms' => $first_tag,
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'terms' => $third_tag,
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                )
            )
        );
        $related = new WP_Query($args);

        if( $related->have_posts() ) {
            while($related->have_posts() ) {
                the_post();

                    $content .= '<ul class="related-posts-box">';
                        $content .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
                    $content .= '</ul>';

            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
    }

    return $content;
}        


add_action('the_content', 'do_jt_related_posts');
function do_jt_related_posts() {


    if( is_singular('post') ) :
        echo get_the_content();
        echo pippin_related_posts();        
    else : 
        echo get_the_content();
    endif;
}
```